# What can I do this with arctan in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I tried this in matlab:

```
arctan(7e8/1.5e14) %rad
```

But I get the following error:

```
Undefined function 'arctan' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Can someone help me with my matlab error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `atan`, not `arctan`:

```
>> atan(7e8/1.5e14)

ans =

  4.6667e-006
```

Comment: Thank you. Why on this document say you can use arctan? http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/arctan.html

Comment: @LearningC - arctan is only for symbolic arguments, in mupad.